# Circuit to enable switching between antennas

Tags: rf, analog, signal, multiplexer, wifi

I'm trying to build my own portable Wi-Fi router that can switch between small internal PCB based antennas (like [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/2-4G-5G-dual-band-antenna-with-5dbi-gain-IPEX-dual-band-internal-antenna-signal-booster/32241447988.html) from Aliexpress) and an external directional antenna.

Is there  circuit that I can make that can work as a switch between these two different analogue signal inputs? Something that switches automatically based on whether an external antenna's connected would be ideal but not necessary. Is a signal multiplexer (and demultiplexer) at least part of what I need?

Thanks!

Comment: They bias pin diodes as RF switches with careful layout. https://www.digikey.ca/en/articles/techzone/2016/dec/how-and-why-to-use-pin-diodes-for-rf-switching

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, that's a great resource, thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

You can buy [SMT coaxial connectors that contain a switch](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/coaxial-connectors-rf/437?k=&pkeyword=&pv5=4787&FV=ffe001b5&mnonly=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25). The antenna input is switched based on whether anything is plugged into the connector.

Just filter results by the feature "internal switch" or search for the term "RF micro-switch".

Comment: Thanks, but these look like really small connectors (smaller even than TS5/9) I guess these wouldn't work if I had pigtails connected to them which may or may not have SMA or N-Type antennas connected downstream?

Comment: @ReverendT That's right, they switch when anything is plugged in, not only when a proper antenna is plugged in.